# strange window positioning after launcher click

Tags: unity, launcher, window

There is a strange and annoying thing in 12.04LTS: Sometimes (quite often indeed) when I click a launcher icon of an application that is running in a unity desktop different from the one I'm actually working in this app's window is repositioned somewhere between the desktops, e.g. the upper half of the window appears in the upper left desktop, and the lower half in the lower left desktop. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post a screenshot, I hope you can imagine.

I've got the feeling that whether the problem occurs or not has got somethng to do with the total number of open windows but I'm not sure about that.

Is there anything to prevent that? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer it is a question, I am not able to comment in other peoples questions yet ( not enough rep ) So, when you say working in multiple desktops are we talking about the different unity desktops? Or are you connected to an external monitor and your windows are opening/maximizing in between monitors?

Comment: sorry for being inexact. We're talking about different unity desktops